# Using onEdit Scripts to add formulas for new data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, edit, spreadsheet

I'm currently using webhooks to populate a google sheet through automate.io mapping.  Essentially, each time the webhook runs a new row is added to a specific tab in my google sheet. This can happen while I'm in the sheet or not.  I then have a set of formulas to run on the data that was just entered.  So far I can only get it to work by going into my sheet, selecting my cells and dragging down the formula.  Through some research I also found this (below) but it doesn't trigger when a new row is added, this only triggers when I modify the formula.  Ideally, I'd like the formula for my 7 columns to be automatically added when a new row is created (with or without me physically in the spreadsheet).  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
  function onEdit(e){
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var tabs = ['Update'];
  var columns = [9,10,11,12,13,14]; 
  if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){
    var cell = e.range;
    var col = cell.getColumn();
  if(columns.indexOf(col) !== -1){
    if(cell.getFormula() !== ""){
       var destination = activeSheet.getRange(2, col, activeSheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
       cell.copyTo(destination);
    }
  }//IF column matches
}//IF tab name matches
}
```

Comment: That is normal behavior because onEdit triggers only fire when a user initiates an edit. [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)

Comment: You only other option is to utiize a timebased trigger to poll for the need to run the appropriate function.

Comment: @Cooper I'll take a look into that, thanks!